# Select data from multiple tables in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a database with multiple tables that I am selecting from. In some tables I have 2 entries fr the same case and while selecting I want to retrieve both those values. My issue is if out of 8 tables 2 tables have two entries for a column then in the final output i see 4 rows for the same case with columns populated from all the tables which makes it difficult to know which columns have two entries.
Example

Table1:

```
case_id company_id date location_type
1 123 08-07-2020 rest1
2 234 01-01-1999 rest2
3 456 01-01-1995 rest1
```

Table2:

```
Case_id type Series
1 A ABCD
1 A GEFT
2 B TRFG
3 A HJKL
```

Table3:

```
Case_id type Series
1 A UIPO
2 A GGTH
3 B TYUI
```

The query:

```
SELECT Table1.company_id,"|",Table2.type, Table3.type FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.case_id = Table2.case_id
LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table1.case_id = Table3.case_id
where Table1.location_type = "rest1"
```

This is what I get:

```
company_id type type
123 A A
123 A A
456 A B
```

How do I get:

```
company_id type type
123 A A
123 A NULL
456 A B
```

Comment: phpmyadmin isn't a database, it's a web application for querying and managing MySQL databases.

Comment: @Barmar Hey, thanks for pointing that out. I mistyped. Edited now.

Comment: You only get `NULL` if there's no matching row in Table3. But Table3 does have a matching row for `case_id = 1`, so both rows are filled in with that `Table3.type`.

Comment: It looks like you need an aditional condition to `LEFT JOIN Table3`, otherwise it will not be NULL joining by `case_id` only

Comment: Joining is a cross product of all the related rows. It's not filling in the rows sequentially, so it will multiply the matches.

Comment: Your query give the right result.  What's your logic to get the result you want???  I don't think any query will give you the result you want.